# How can I incorporate my C++ code into my Xcode project using an Executable file?

Tags: c++, xcode, executable

I am new to Xcode, and I simply want to see if it is possible to use an executable file in Xcode. To test this, I have a very simple C++ code that prints the user's input to the screen.

I am working with a swift-based project in Xcode 10. In the project build settings, I can see the linking section which seems like the appropriate place for a executable file to be placed, however all of the info I have found has been about generating an executable file from the Xcode project, which is the opposite of what I need (to incorporate an external executable file into my Xcode project). Here is the main code from the C++ file from which I generated the executable file.

```
int CPPTest::main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
int counter;
//  printf("Program Name Is: %s", argv[0]);
if (argc == 1)
printf("\nNo Extra Command Line Argument Passed Other Than Program Name\n");
if (argc >= 2)
{
    printf("\nNumber Of Arguments Passed: %d", argc);
    printf("\n----Following Are The Command Line Arguments Passed----\n");
    for (counter = 0; counter<argc; counter++)
    printf("argv[%d]: %s\n", counter, argv[counter]);
}
//  system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

I would greatly appreciate step-by-step instructions as to how to link my executable file with my Xcode project, and to be able to call the main function and pass the parameters.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I send parameters to and run my executable file in Xcode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57153407/how-can-i-send-parameters-to-and-run-my-executable-file-in-xcode)

Answer (score 1):

If it's an iOS project, you won't be able to run the C++ executable file directly. You could create a library for the C++ code by adding a target to your project and link the library with your Swift app. The following Stack Overflow question should help:

[How to build and use a C++ static library for ios application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18811072/how-to-build-and-use-a-c-static-library-for-ios-application)

If it's a Mac project, you can use the Process (formerly called NSTask) class to run the C++ executable and supply the parameters. You have to add the executable file to your project, add a Copy Files build phase to your Swift app project to copy the C++ executable to your app bundle, and write some Swift code to load the C++ executable from the app bundle.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! It is an iOS project. I have a general understanding of how to add a target or a framework and then link that to my project. I don't know how I would successfully add C++ files to a library? Would I need to wrap those files in Objective-C in the library, and then add the library? Alternatively, which template would be best for the new target that you recommended to create? Thanks.

Comment: I updated my answer with a link to a Stack Overflow question on using a C++ library in iOS. If you need more help and are unable to find any other Stack Overflow questions on using C++ libraries in iOS, ask a new question. You have too many questions for me to answer in a comment. I can tell you to use the target membership checkboxes on the right side of the window to make the C++ files members of the library target.